# Do includes in .cpp file get included when a .h file is included

Tags: c++

So lets say I have a bunch of files named like this :

- `main.cpp` : Containing the main() function
- `foo.h` : declaration for some resource
- `foo.cpp` : definition of the resource declared in `foo.h`
- `goo.h` : declaration of some other resource

Now `foo.cpp` includes `goo.h`

```cpp
// foo.cpp

#include "goo.h"
//...
//...
```

**My question is that if I include `foo.h` in `main.cpp` file, can I access definitions in `goo.h` in my `main.cpp` file? or i would need to include `goo.h` in `main.cpp`?**

```cpp
// main.cpp
#include "foo.h"

int main() {
  // Can i access the definitions in goo.h here without including goo.h??
}
```

Do let me know if you need further clarifications. TIA!

Comment: Have you tried compiling and running such a program?

Comment: I will say the same! Try it yourself!

Comment: No, and you should try it. `cpp's` include only what they are told. It would be inefficient to do ohterwise.

Comment: I downvoted this question because you could have easily checked this yourself.

Comment: Note that in most cases each translation unit (source file) is compiled separately. When building `main.cpp` the compiler need not know of the existence of `foo.cpp`

Comment: I am working on a massive MFC application written a while back and there are problems with the includes in this application.  There are 100s of files and each file has almost 2000 lines of code and hence it was easier for me to ask a question on SO rather than messing around the codebase and break things without even knowing.

Comment: When I have situations like this I make a simple test project.

Comment: Yes, but this project is built on a PAL and 3 other projects for processing data. Hence it was much easier to post a question than to recreate a minimal version of the project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> if I include foo.h in main.cpp file, can I access definitions in goo.h in my main.cpp file?

Depends on what `foo.h` contains. If it includes `goo.h`, then you can technically access those definitions in `main.cpp`. Inclusion is a transitive "operation". If `c` includes `b`, and `b` includes `a`, then `c` includes `a` indirectly.

If `foo.h` does not include `goo.h` (either directly or indirectly), then there is no reason why including `foo.h` would cause `goo.h` to be included.

> Do includes in .cpp file get included when a .h file is included

No.

While inclusion is transitive, it is not symmetric. `foo.cpp` includes `foo.h`, but `foo.h` does not include `foo.cpp`.

---

Note that it is typically a bad practice to depend on definitions/declarations from a transitively included header.

> or i would need to include goo.h in main.cpp?

If in `main.cpp` you depend on definitions/declarations from `goo.h`, then you should include `goo.h` in `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 3):

If you neither include a header file directly in your code file nor include a header file that does include it indirectly, then that header file will not be used when compiling your code file. Nothing in it will be accessible.